# Minimality of the Spatial C*-Norm

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-theory, tensor-products, c-star-algebras

Given C*-Algebras $A,B$ and $x \in A \otimes_* B$ show that:

**(a)** If $(\tau \otimes_* \rho)(x)=0$ for all $\tau \in A_+^*$ and $\rho \in B_+^*$, then $x=0$.

PS: $\tau \in A_+^*$ means that $\tau$ is positive functional on $A$.

**(b)** Can I guarantee the same result for all functional?

Anyone can help me? 
I'm not seeing how to use the minimality of the spatial C*-norm.

Thanks!